# Select products to get maximum cart value

Tags: algorithm, oop, logic

Given a list of products available in the store, i need to select set of products to my cart in such a way that, my cart value should be maximum it can.
Restrictions are like, cart has a dimension `l*w*h`. Products selected should individually and totally fit into the cart giving maximum possible value to cart. One 1 item per product can be selected.

I have `product id`, `price`, `l`, `w`, `ht`, `weight` of each product with me. How can this be accomplished???

I came up with a logic as below.

1. Calculate volume of the cart
2. Calculate volume of product and value of product per cubic cm using its price
3. Sort the product list based on value/cucm
4. Start adding products from the sorted list like 1st, 2nd , 3rd, etc. till the cart gets filled.
5. If a product cannot fit into the cart, skip it and select the next possible product from the sorted list.
6. Once list is obtained, check if any product in the selected list can be replaced with another product with less volume but results in more cart value.

But this is not getting me the correct product list with maximum cart value. What is the problem in the above logic?

Comment: This sounds like a Knapsack problem, which you could solve using dynamic programming techniques: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem. Remember that the Knapsack Problem is NP-complete, so the algorithm will take a long time for big product lists.

Comment: The problem with your logic is that the decision "Should I put this product into my cart" is not necessarily determined by the value/cost ratio but also by other factors like "Are there substitutional products A and B which have a higher (combined) value/cost ratio if I put them in my cart instead of product C".

Answer (score 1):

Are the three dimensions integer valued with some finite bound ? Then it can be solved with dynamic programming. But I think there should some assumptions made, e.g. the partition of sub-problems should be end-to-end cutting planes etc. Without that dynamic programming would be infeasible.

The key trick here is that you need to account for possibilities that a box can be oriented in several ways, and it is the number of ways to align its own three dimensions along the three axes of the cart. It is 3! = 6 for three dimensions. So in the dynamic programming when you process the i-th product, include all the 6 ways interpret its 3 dimensions as L,W,H.